# Scala macro - Infer implicit value using `c.prefix`

Tags: scala, scala-macros

`c.inferImplicitValue` infers implicit values in the call site scope. Is it possible to infer implicits using the `c.prefix` scope?

This is not valid code, but expresses what I need:

```
c.prefix.inferImplicitValue
```

I'm currently using a naive implementation for this purpose[1], but it has some limitations like not inferring implicit values from `def`s and detecting duplicated/ambiguous implicit values.

[1] https://github.com/getquill/quill/blob/9a28d4e6c901d3fa07e7d5838e2f4c1f3c16732b/quill-core/src/main/scala/io/getquill/util/InferImplicitValueWithFallback.scala#L12

Comment: What does it mean exactly to infer implicits "using the c.prefix scope"? Should it simply resolve the implicit as if every member of the prefix where in scope? Should it include the companion? Should it exclude implicits in the call site scope or come in addition of it? Also, do you need to get the resolved tree inside your macro (as `inferImplicitValue` does) or would it suffice to generate some tree that would (once compiled) resolve to the correct implicit value?

Comment: It should resolve implicit as if the implicit members of the prefix were imported. It's not necessary to include the companion object. A tree that will infer the implicit value is fine if there aren't alternatives.

Comment: Then something as simple as `q"""{import ${c.prefix}._;     _root_.scala.Predef.implicitly[$T]  }""" ` should do the work (where `T` is an instance of `c.universe.Type` representing the type of the implicit value to lookup). Tell me if it fits the bill, then I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks Régis, but I'd say that it is a workaround. For instance, it would harder or even impossible to implement this kind of logic: https://github.com/getquill/quill/blob/9a28d4e6c901d3fa07e7d5838e2f4c1f3c16732b/quill-core/src/main/scala/io/getquill/norm/select/SelectFlattening.scala#L21

Comment: You mean that you need to know in the macro if the inference worked or not? Then just wrap it in a call to `c.typeCheck` and you'll know if the lookup succeded. Here's an example that uses this idea to implement a macro that returns `None` if the implicit was not found in the prefix context, and otherwise wraps the result in a `Some`: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d56f2253a43b1e3a44d2

Comment: Great! That works for me, feel free to add it as an answer! Some notes: `typeCheck` is deprecated (I've changed it to `type check`) and I'm trying to get rid of the warning "Unused import" that this approach generates for some cases.

Comment: `Context.typeCheck` is deprecated? That's news to me. The scaladoc makes no mention of it even in the latest versions (http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.macros.Context)

Comment: Concerning the "Unused import" warning, it seems it does not affect macro-generated code. In other words, while said import does generate the warning when directly written explictly in your program, when using the macro (which generates that same import) no warning is emitted. Tested with scala.2.11.7 with option `-Ywarn-unused-import`

Comment: It does generate the warning for me if the implicit is not found. I'm using scala 2.11.7, sbt 0.13.8 and `-Ywarn-unused-import`.

Comment: Example of warning https://travis-ci.org/getquill/quill#L664

Comment: Well I've quickly looked at your code and to be honest I have no idea why you get that warning. Sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply generating a block with an appropriate (local) import followed by a call to `implicitly` does the trick:

```
q"""{import ${c.prefix}._; _root_.scala.Predef.implicitly[$T] }
```

Where `T` is an instance of `Type` representing the type of the implicit value to lookup.

To check if the implicit lookup actually succeeded, you can call `Context.typeCheck` with `silent=true` and check if the resulting tree is empty or not.

As an illustration, here is an example that implements an `infer` method returning `None` if the implicit was not found in the members of the target object, and otherwise wraps the result in a `Some`.

```
import scala.reflect.macros.Context
import scala.language.experimental.macros

def inferImplicitInPrefixContext[T:c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val T = weakTypeOf[T]
  c.typeCheck(
    q"""{
      import ${c.prefix}._
      _root_.scala.Predef.implicitly[$T]
    }""",
    silent = true
  )
}

def infer_impl[T:c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[Option[T]] = {
  import c.universe._
  c.Expr[Option[T]](
    inferImplicitInPrefixContext[T](c) match {
      case EmptyTree => q"_root_.scala.None"
      case tree => q"_root_.scala.Some($tree)"
    }
  )
}

trait InferOp {
  def infer[T]: Option[T] = macro infer_impl[T]
}
```

Let's test it:

```
object Foo extends InferOp {
  implicit val s = "hello"
}

Foo.infer[String] // res0: Some[String] = Some(hello)

Foo.infer[Int] // res1: None.type = None

implicit val lng: Long = 123L

Foo.infer[Long] // res2: Some[Long] = Some(123)
```