# How to get implicits available via Scala reflection?

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm writing a parser-generator that creates Scala case classes.  Take this example:

```
case class Foo(
   name : String,
   age : Int
)(implicit other:Int){}
```

When I want to materialize a Foo instance my parser-generator has knowledge of all 3 members, including the implicit 'other'.  I have the data to populate name & age.

Using Scala reflection, how can I inspect the "implicit environment" when the object will be created to find an appropriate value for 'other'?

Comment: You can supply implicit values 'non-implicitly', eg: `Foo("hi", 1)(100)`

Comment: I need to use reflection at runtime to create the class--like parsers do.  Your example is compile-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't: the implicits available depend on things like imports, local variables, etc. which aren't available at runtime at all. If you can get away with a macro, there is the `c.inferImplicitValue` method. See [Scala macro - Infer implicit value using `c.prefix`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603946/scala-macro-infer-implicit-value-using-c-prefix) or https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-language/rqNZMBuJLtE for some examples, but if you want help with this route I advise asking a separate question.