# How to Find Available Implicit Conversions for a Given Type in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection, autocomplete

I am writing an autocompleter (i.e., code completion like in Eclipse or IntelliJ) for a domain specific language that is a subset of Scala. Users frequently use implicit conversions to hide the more advanced features of Scala like options or Scalaz disjunctions.

I am looking for a way, either at compile time or runtime, to acquire a list of implicit conversions available for a receiver (i.e., for the ‘x’ in ‘val y = x.foo’). So, I have two specific questions:

1. Is there some library that, given the type of a receiver, can find all the implicit conversions that the compiler could use to turn that receiver into another type?*
2. How is the identification of available implicit conversions actually done by the Scala compiler? I am not sure where in the source to look to find it; some documentation about how the compiler does this or the location in the source where it does it would also be very helpful.

<sub>*: As you might have guessed, I plan to use the resulting list to get all the available fields and methods of all the types the given variable could be implicitly converted to so that the autocompleter can suggest them all to users. If there’s an even more direct way to do that, that would be great too.</sub>

Comment: While doing some research to compose this question, I found [this other Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683721/how-to-get-implicits-available-via-scala-reflection), but while the title was very promising I wasn't able to understand the rest of the question or its answer.